# Responsive Nav Menu disappear after ToggleSlide() using Media query and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I am trying to create a Responsive drop down nav for smartphones.thingd works fine before clicking on the toggle btn but after cliking on that the nav also got hidden in bigger wide as well.I know that this is not gonna be obvious on phone screen because that is the screen size which user is using and infact he/she is not able to swich to wide screen size on that device but I would like to know the logic of the issue and how to prevent it.
Here is my HTM code:

```
<a id="toggleMenu" href="#">Welcome</a>
   <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/work/">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/clients/">Recent Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
<div class="banner"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
.nav {
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  border-width: 0px 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  display:none;
}
.nav li {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:310px;
  background:#175e4c;
}
#toggleMenu {
  display:  inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width:281px;
}
```

and finally the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#toggleMenu").click(function () {
 $('.nav').slideToggle();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue.

Here is what I added to my javascript to fix it:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 480) // or 768
        $('#.YourMenuIdOrClass').show();
});
```

You may want to change the 480 to 768 in your code though.